# How to configure the routes so that my spa starts in the path /admin?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I try to create a basic spa, but I want to use the basic authentication of laravel and not create a login system in vue, after logging in, it redirects me to the route `/admin` **where I want it to be the entry point of my spa**, try with this configuration and it shows nothing.

**web.php**  -> routing

```
Route::get('/admin/{any}',function(){
    return view('app');
})->where('any','.*')->name('admin')->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/admin',function(){
    return view('app');
})->name('admin')->middleware('auth');


Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('showLoginForm');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

in my app view, I have the app file compiled with the following routes

```
const routes = [

    {
        path: '/admin',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "routes" */`~/Pages/Layouts/Admin`), 
        meta: { requiresAuth: true },
        children: [
            {
                path : '/', name : 'Home',
                component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "routes" */`~/Pages/Admin/Home`),
                meta: { },
            },
            { 
                path : 'usuarios',
                component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "routes" */`~/Pages/Admin/Usuarios/Index`),
                meta: { },
                children : [
                    {

                    }
                ]
            },

            { 
                path: '403',
                name:'403', 
                component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "routes" */`~/Pages/Errors/403`)
            },
        ]
    },

]

export default routes;
```

the routes I'm looking for is `misite.com/admin/users` for example, of course the path users would be a route of my vueRouter

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to redirect your users after login with auth laravel system to `/admin` path, just go to `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` and edit the `$redirectTo` attribute like this:

`$redirectTo = '/admin'`

as mentioned in laravel doc :

> When a user is successfully authenticated, they
>   will be redirected to the /home URI. You can customize the
>   post-authentication redirect location by defining a redirectTo
>   property on the  LoginController, RegisterController, ResetPasswordController, and  VerificationController.

for more information please check the doc [Path Customization
Laravel after login](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#included-authenticating)

Comment: That was already done, from that redirection, ie from that route admin, I would like my spa to have that route as root and the main one as in most examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in web.php file.

```
Route::any('/admin/{all}', function () {
    if ( ! Auth::user() ){
    return redirect('/login');
    }
    return view('admin'); //SPA app
})
->where(['all' => '.*']);
```

Also, in your Vue routes, you need to use entrypoint of your URL `/admin` in path like this. This is just an example for moving to dashboard like `/admin/dashboard`

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/admin/dashboard",
        component: Dashboard,
        name: "dashboard",
        meta: {
            title: "Dashboard",
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    }
];
```